# A state with no more possible moves

Tags: checkers

We ran into a state in a game of Checkers, where there were no more possible moves. Is this situation even possible according to the correct rules (I'm not an experienced player)? And if so, is it a draw? And if not, who wins (I'd assume white, because he jumped a piece)?

If the situation is possible, is it common? What about professional setting?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this set of [the rules](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/play-checkers-using-standard-rules-409287):

> A player wins the game when the opponent cannot make a move. In most cases, this is because all of the opponent's pieces have been captured, but it could also be because all of his pieces are blocked in.

So you win if your opponent can't move.

I have had this situation several times with draughts which is similar to checkers.

Comment: There's a section in the rules that states if a capture can be made, it MUST be made.  Alternate moves that do not result in a capture cannot be performed.  In order to make it into the state described above, one, or both, of the players would have to violate this rule, so I don't think it's actually possible to get into this particular state.  I can see a case where one player only has 2 pieces left and gets blocked in to a corner, but not with all pieces still available on the board.

Comment: @CodeMonkey and still I have been there. But I can't remember the moves because it must be 35+ years ago.